# How to add Qualtrics script programatically

Tags: javascript, html, dom, localhost, qualtrics

I need to inject Qualtrics script after sucessful login

I got this peice of code from Qualtrics to add into my code

```
<!--BEGIN QUALTRICS WEBSITE FEEDBACK SNIPPET-->
<script type='text/javascript'>
(function()\{var g=function(e,h,f,g)\{\
this.get=function(a)\{for(var a=a+"=",c=document.cookie.split(";"),b=0,e=c.length;b<e;b++)\{for(var d=c[b];" "==d.charAt(0);)d=d.substring(1,d.length);if(0==d.indexOf(a))return d.substring(a.length,d.length)\}return null\};\
this.set=function(a,c)\{var b="",b=new Date;b.setTime(b.getTime()+6048E5);b="; expires="+b.toGMTString();document.cookie=a+"="+c+b+"; path=/; "\};\
this.check=function()\{var a=this.get(f);if(a)a=a.split(":");else if(100!=e)"v"==h&&(e=Math.random()>=e/100?0:100),a=[h,e,0],this.set(f,a.join(":"));else return!0;var c=a[1];if(100==c)return!0;switch(a[0])\{case "v":return!1;case "r":return c=a[2]%Math.floor(100/c),a[2]++,this.set(f,a.join(":")),!c\}return!0\};\
this.go=function()\{if(this.check())\{var a=document.createElement("script");a.type="text/javascript";a.src=g;document.body&&document.body.appendChild(a)\}\};\
this.start=function()\{var t=this;"complete"!==document.readyState?window.addEventListener?window.addEventListener("load",function()\{t.go()\},!1):window.attachEvent&&window.attachEvent("onload",function()\{t.go()\}):t.go()\};\};\
try\{(new g(100,"r","QSI_S_ZN_bNn0ZfSFXk2WDY2","https://znbnn0zfsfxk2wdy2-example.siteintercept.qualtrics.com/SIE/?Q_ZID=ZN_bNn0ZfSFXk2WDY2")).start()\}catch(i)\{\}\})();\
</script>
<div id='ZN_bNn0ZfSFXk2WDY2'><!--DO NOT REMOVE-CONTENTS PLACED HERE--></div>\
<!--END WEBSITE FEEDBACK SNIPPET-->}
```

but instead of injecting this code directly, I have made this function and called after successful login

```
    public loadQualtricsScript(): void {
        const qualtricsScript = document.createElement("script"); 
        qualtricsScript.defer = true;
        qualtricsScript.src = "https://znbnn0zfsfxk2wdy2-example.siteintercept.qualtrics.com/SIE/?Q_ZID=ZN_bNn0ZfSFXk2WDY2";
        document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(qualtricsScript);
        qualtricsScript.onerror = () => {
            console.error("Error occurred while loading the Qualtrics script");
        };
    }
```

Please Note:

- I am not included any div into my HTML
- I have not added any JavaScript (IIFE mentioned above) in my script

Suspiciously, my code is working on my local
but I am worried if it will work on development/production or not

Please help me if I am going right or not?

Comment: I am not familiar with Qualtrics, but you likely need to add the div with ID to the DOM within your function as well

Comment: If you prettify their script you see that they read and set a cookie, and conditionally append the script tag with URL to the body based on the cookie